# Windows 10 (Pre-Anniversary update) Hyper-V client problems with DPI and connection bar

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-10-v1511, high-dpi

I'm using a laptop for work that is completely locked down, with Hyper-V host enabled and a VM with full admin rights for doing anything I can't do on the laptop's host OS.

The laptop is running Windows 10 Enterpise without the Anniversary Update. The VM I'm using is running the Anniversary Update. I have two problems for which I cannot find a solution yet.

1. Is there any way to completely disable the connection bar in full screen mode? I know this is possible with RDP connections, but I can't find the setting anywhere for Hyper-V connections. I know I can auto-hide it, but that doesn't work well at all since any time I move my mouse to the top of the screen (to close a tab, for instance), it slides into view.
2. How do I change DPI scaling for the virtual machine so that my 13" 1080p display uses 100% DPI scaling in the VM? Everything is unusably huge compared to the host OS. I tried the LogPixels registry entry (set it to 96) but that didn't do anything. The Settings app indicates I'm at 100% scaling, but this is definitely not the case.

This is what I mean:

### [image: DPI difference]

*Edit to clarify why I'm specifying Anniversary Update: I am running the Anniversary Update in the VM, with Windows 10 Enterprise. The Anniversary Update is available for Enterprise through MSDN, although it is has not been released outside of MSDN and the Windows Insider Program yet. There have been changes to Hyper-V and DPI scaling in the Anniversary Update, which is the reason I specified that the host is pre-update and the client is not.*

Comment: Have you contacted your IT Administrator for assistance in this matter?

Comment: I imagine connecting via RDP will solve both of those problems

Comment: @adampski - I think you're right...but unfortunately the host machine is on a segregated VLAN, so RDP doesn't work - I just tried.

Comment: Then surely putting the VM on the same vlan ID would allow them both to talk?

Comment: That won't really work - the segregated VLAN is basically useless for anything I need the VM for (which is anything I can't do on the secured host). i think I might be SOL. :(